# Lack of some manual entries

Tags: virtualbox, manpage

I tried to find some manual entries e.g. `man 3p printf`, `man stdlib.h` (in general any posix section 3 entries, nor C libraries), but I'm getting a message that there are no manual entries for them. The only thing I could find on the Internet was that I should run `sudo mandb` to update `man`, but it didn't help.

Could the fact that I'm running Ubuntu using VirtualBox or that I did "minimal installation" somehow be the cause?

Comment: To answer your actual question, the answer is yes. Man pages don't get installed when you install a minimal installation. For you, and future readers, [here is a link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-install-man-pages-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Answer (score 0):

After installing `manpages-posix-dev`, the problem seems to be solved.